# Mysql: How to update current rows with the value of current - x row's value?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table `b` with million of rows. i want to update column `result` with the previous nth row's value (say previous 3rd row's value). The code below can update  `result` with  previous row's value at a very high speed as i have not used `join`. However, it cant update the   `result` with previous 3rd row's value.

```
set @previousRow = 0.0;
ALTER TABLE b ADD previousRow Double;
UPDATE `b` SET `result`=@previousRow , previousRow = @previousRow:=`x`;
ALTER TABLE b DROP previousRow;
```

The query above do this at very high speed:

```
id, x, result
1 , 4, 0.0
2 , 6, 4
3 , 5, 6
4 , 6, 5
5 , 5, 6
6 , 3, 5
7 , 2, 3
```

What i want to do

```
id, x, result
1 , 4, null
2 , 6, null
3 , 5, null
4 , 6, 4
5 , 5, 6
6 , 3, 5
7 , 2, 6
8 , 7, 5
9 , 9, 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'd need N variables, ie for 3 rows you'd need something like this:

```
set @previousRow1 = 0.0,@previousRow2 = 0.0,@previousRow3 = 0.0;
ALTER TABLE b ADD previousRow Double;
UPDATE `b` SET `result`=@previousRow1 
      , @previousRow1 = @previousRow2
      , @previousRow2 = @previousRow3
      , @previousRow3 = `x`;
```

Not sure about the syntax in MySQL exactly, can't test it presently.

Of course in most other DBMS you could use LEAD/LAG functions, I don't think there's a solution in MySQL that doesn't involve joins.

Comment: is LEAD/LAG functions available MS Sql 2003 ? is it as fast/faster than using variable?

Comment: is there extension which i can install to enable mysql to achieve the prob?

Comment: LEAD/LAG didn't come around until MS SQL 2012, they were late to the party.  I don't think there's any way around it in MySQL that wouldn't involve joins.

Comment: that's sad :(. i'm shifting the entire code to VB.NET. MySql seems to be fast. But where then update is complicated, MySql is as slow as an wounded tortoise especially when we use joins:(

Comment: The query dont work, error due to var. *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@previousRow1 := @previousRow2
      at line 2 *

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure about the syntax, just the logic.  I agree with others, if you want any number N it's going to require a join, or a badass cursor/loop that will set up N variables in the pattern above.  Seems like with proper indexing the join might be faster at that point.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works in MySQL:

```
create table b (id int, x int, result int);

insert into b(id, x)
    select 1 , 4 union all
    select 2 , 6 union all
    select 3 , 5 union all
    select 4 , 6 union all
    select 5 , 5 union all
    select 6 , 3 union all
    select 7 , 2;

set @prev1 = NULL;
set @prev2 = NULL;
set @prev3 = NULL;
alter table b add col int;
update b
    set result = @prev3,
        col = (@prev3 := @prev2),
        col = (@prev2 := @prev1),
        col = (@prev1 := x);
alter table b drop col;
```

You can test this at [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9456b/1).

Comment: well, u have used 3 variables as the question is to bet 3rd previous row. But sometimes if i want to get the previous 1000th row, then?

Comment: @NokImchen . . . Have an autoincrementing id and use a join.

Comment: i want to avoid joins as it makes the query very slow